# Error connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock in node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm running scotch box (a vagrant LAMP stack) on Windows.

I have no problems connecting to MySQL normally through PHP or Navicat.

but I'm trying to connect to it in `Node.js` and I get the error "`Error connecting to MySQL: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306`"

From what I've understood by searching around it seems that I need to set the socket path

but when I do that I get the error "`Error connecting to MySQL: Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`"

I am 100% sure this is the correct socket path. I've SSHed into vagrant and verified that mysqld.sock is actually there and it is correctly set in /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Skip networking is also OFF.

I've also tried setting the bind-address to 0.0.0.0 and commenting out the bind-address entirely, renaming mysqld.sock and restarting the mysql server so that it would recreate mysqld.sock again. Also tried disabling my firewall (node.js is allowed anyway) and reinstalling MySQL.

None of this has worked and the error has remained the same: "`Error connecting to MySQL: Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`"

this is the code I have so far:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'test',
  socketPath : '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
   console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
   });
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't your `socketPath` path be set to: `'/var/lib/mysqld/mysqld.sock'` instead of `'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`?

Comment: I see I had the wrong error pasted. Originally I thought it was /var/lib before I confirmed it as /var/run/. To be 100% clear the error I'm getting now is '`Error: connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`'. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I search for mysql socket on a scotchbox machine using `sudo find / -type s` and it seems that the socket is located under `/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Tried that and got this error: "`Error: connect ENOENT /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`". I got the same result as you when I ran "`sudo find / -type s`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve it.

All you have to do is comment out bind-address in my.cnf and connect using the IP of the site.

In my case it was 192.168.33.10 (This is what scotchbox sets it to by default).

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '192.168.33.10',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'root',
  database : 'test'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to MySQL: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
   console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
   });
```

Comment: no working even after commenting out bind-address and using IP-address for connection

Answer (score 0):

The file you need to edit is **/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf**

comment out the **bind-address** line in this file and you should be fine.