# rror: connect ENOENT /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

i have a problem that i cant use mysql server. so i asked the solution in stackoverflow and other error was happend..

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "root",
  password: "111111",
  database: "opentutorials",
  socketPath: "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock"
});

connection.connect();

connection.query("SELECT * FROM topic", function(error, results, fields) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  console.log(results);
});

connection.end();
```

here is my code and the error

Error: connect ENOENT /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
    at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1106:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/junggri/Desktop/mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/junggri/Desktop/mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/junggri/Desktop/mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:119:18)
    at Object. (/Users/junggri/Desktop/mysql/nodejs/mysql.js:11:12)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
  fatal: true }

Comment: maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455815/error-connect-enoent-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-in-node-js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error connect ENOENT /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40455815/error-connect-enoent-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock-in-node-js)

Comment: In your prior post someone said you might not have `mysql` running locally. Did you test and confirm that? If you open `Activity Monitor` and search for `mysqld`, do you see a result - do you see more than one?